# When slideshow showing last image then showing alert

Tags: jquery

I have simple slideshow jquery code.
I want when showing last img then show some alert or do something.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function()
  {
    $('.img:gt(0)').hide();
    setInterval(function() {
      $(".img:first-child").fadeOut(3000).next(".img").fadeIn(3000).end().appendTo("#show-case")
    }, 4000);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to stackoverflow. Please formulate a clear question and the error you encounter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try,

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.img:gt(0)').hide();

    setInterval(
       function() {
        $(".img:first-child")
        .fadeOut(3000)
        .next(".img")
        .fadeIn(3000).end().appendTo("#show-case");

       if($('.img').length - $('#show-case .img').length == 0)
         {
              alert("last image..!")
         }

       }, 4000);
});
```

Comment: @user3104879 can you create a demo of it.? or just show the structure of your html.

Comment: <script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.img:gt(0)').hide();
 var increment = 0;
    setInterval(
 
       function() {
        $(".img:first-child")
        .fadeOut(3000)
        .next(".img")
        .fadeIn(3000).appendTo("#show-case");
  increment++;
        
  if(increment == $('.img').length ){
   alert('last img');
   false
   }
              
        

       }, 4000);
});


</script>